# Цикл не выполняется

Tags: c#

Почему цикл не выполняется и проходит значение ЛЧМ.Faza = 23?

```
        ЛЧМ[0] = 0;
        i = 0;
        ЛЧМ.Faza = 23;
        while (ЛЧМ[0] >-0.1 && ЛЧМ[0] < -0.2 ) 
        {
            ЛЧМ.Faza = i  * 2*Math.PI / 10000;
            ЛЧМ[0] = Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * F0 * (n / 2 - 0) * (-T_d) + BASA * Math.Pow(((n / 2 - 0) * T_d), 2) / 2 + ЛЧМ.Faza);
            ++i;
        }
```

Мне нужно найти такое ЛЧМ.Faza, при котором ЛЧМ[0] будет лежать между -0.1 и -0.2

Comment: чему равно начальное значение ЛЧМ[0] ?

Comment: ЛЧМ[0] = 0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(ЛЧМ[0] >-0.1 && ЛЧМ[0] < -0.2 )
```

Это выражение всегда ложно. Наверно хотели написать (или еще как то по другому):

```
(ЛЧМ[0] <-0.1 && ЛЧМ[0] > -0.2 )
```

Comment: все равно проходит значение ЛЧМ.Faza = 23

Comment: посмотрите на строку ЛЧМ.Faza = i  * 2*Math.PI / 10000;
тут рассчитывается это значение, а это первая строка цикла. Поэтому, какое начальное значение  ЛЧМ.Faza не задали, все равно оно будет перевычисленно.

Comment: @Vezd Вы логику изучали когда-нибудь? При начальном значении ЛЧМ[0] = 0; разумеется цикл не будет выполняться.

Исправьте или начальное значение или условие. Например, ЛЧМ[0]>=0 :) Но, какое именно должно быть условие, все равно кроме Вас не знает. Задача то Ваша и Вам решать как она должна работать.

Comment: С одним условием я понимаю как написать, а как написать  чтобы находилось ЛЧМ.Faza, при котором ЛЧМ[0] будет лежать между -0.1 и -0.2, я не могу понять

Comment: @Vezd Условие между -0.1 и -0.2 я уже написал, но 0 между этими числами не находиться - Вы это понимаете? По этому при начальном условии =0 цикл не выполниться.

Comment: разобрался